# Change some column's classes to integer

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table as following :-

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(one = as.character(2011:2020), two = rep(2, times = 10),
                three = rep(3, times = 10), four = rep(4, times = 10),
                five = rep(5, times = 5))
```

I want to change the columns `two`, `three` and `four` to `integer` from `numeric`. Using the following code:-

```
a[, lapply(.SD, as.integer), .SDcols = colnames(a)[-c(1, 4)]]
```

they do change to `integer`, but this only returns columns `two`, `three` and `four`. Columns `one` and `five` are missing.

I want to know if there is a `data.table` way which can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dplyr  has an elegant method to do this.  

a %>%  mutate_if(is.numeric, as.integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.SDcols` in the following way -

```
library(data.table)

cols <- 2:4
#column names work as well
#cols <- c('two', 'three', 'four')

a[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.integer), .SDcols = cols]
a

#     one two three four five
# 1: 2011   2     3    4    5
# 2: 2012   2     3    4    5
# 3: 2013   2     3    4    5
# 4: 2014   2     3    4    5
# 5: 2015   2     3    4    5
# 6: 2016   2     3    4    5
# 7: 2017   2     3    4    5
# 8: 2018   2     3    4    5
# 9: 2019   2     3    4    5
#10: 2020   2     3    4    5

str(a)

#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ one  : chr  "2011" "2012" "2013" "2014" ...
# $ two  : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
# $ three: int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
# $ four : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
# $ five : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(cols), as.integer))
```